# Dropping a question, and then just logging out and leaving

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

This is an etiquette and maybe even rules question.

I take the questions I ask seriously over at StackExchange. I form my question in an editor, I check for clarity and make edits, I take care to present my code nicely. I adhere to the idea that doing all that is like talking to the stuffed frog in the corner of the IT office analogy; I often see my own answer in my work while creating a conscientious question. I even wait to post it, and when I'm ready, it's like handing in a formal essay to me, like for grades.

The point is, it's enough of a big deal to me, and a rarity that I even post a question, that (and here's where I get to my point) ... that *I stick around for five minutes, at least, me longer ... to see if anyone immediatey engages my question.*

So, today ... a first time user, first question from them ever at stackexchange ... drops their fairly advanced question, upon which I engaged almost immediately. I found them an answer on the stack, and posted. I decided to explore the answer myself because I'm working with similar stuff myself, so was interested ... but did from the context of solving *their* problem.

I find that old answer has not just deprecated parts, but methods that don't even exist in the dependency anymore. So ... and this is now four hours later ... I post that the original answer is not cutting it, take a different path, and post the first time questioner my full code of how *I* do what they are trying, through a different approach.

Four hours later ... and not once had the asker engaged me. They walked across the office ... asked for help ... and while I engaged *their* problem, they promptly excused themselves and went for coffee. Just as I sat down and started to help them with their code. My first response was almost immediate. Four hours later, and more engaging ... first time questioner ... and silence. Nothing.

Four hours later ... in a void of silence ... I removed all my posts and code from over the four hours.

It may not be a rule ... but, as a social user, I reserve the right to take note of someone who does that; drops and leaves. I take my questions on stack exchange more seriously than *that*. So, I removed my answers.

What's the etiquette? What's the rule? (The two may not be the same, rule and etiquette.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the way. :) I liked this answer: It's not unreasonable to want posters to keep tabs on everything happening with their question immediately after asking, but you'll be happier if you do what you can and don't worry about it.

Comment: How do you know the questioner "went for coffee"?  Maybe they had their internet connection broken or had to handle an emergency.

Comment: No, they just came back later and acted like the entitled twit they were. It's really no problem. I just will remember the handle and not answer their questions. And that, is my prerogative. Emergency. Ha! Let's get real, I was trying to be.

Comment: And I'll add, since someone was interested, that I was the only person who engaged them, but for one other person, who was just critical of their question in a simple comment. And because I retracted my full solution to their question, they now have nothing. Not even engagement from anyone. Seems like everything ended up for the best. And really, I'm over it. I just wanted to let people know how whacked that is to behave that way. The questioner is left with an empty thread, thumb out in the wind. And they had a solution, right there. Grins now. I think it's obnoxious conduct.

Comment: @Lotsa I understand your frustration, but please remember that we don't only post an answer for OP, bug for any other future user coming across the question when looking for solutions. I find that idea more rewarding than playing "personal help desk". So I wouldn't remove a useful answer just because OP doesn't react: it could still get recognition from others.

Comment: @Lotsa Another thing that worked for me was reminding OP in a comment that they should watch their question when it is posted, clarify if necessary and give feedback to solutions because other users invest their time trying to help them. These comments were usually well received, OPs apologized and mentioned that they weren't aware of that. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I myself was reminded to remember to mark an answer as accepted if it solved the problem. I was upvoting, but forgetting to mark things accepted. So, when I removed my formal answers and code, I left them a small, I thought not too impolite a reminder to stay for at least a moment. I really did answer the first answer within two minutes. That was when, after they returned later, that they responded kind of flippantly. That's when I was not uncomfortable anymore that I had removed the answers. So, I sort of did try that. Maybe I sounded grumpy. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: @Tufkamt And thank you too for reminding me it's about the wider community.

Comment: This community is used by users all over the world.  You could be in an entirely different timezone then this user.  You shouldn't remove good answers to questions that can be answered.